# Celery and django does not work as expected

Tags: django, cron, celery, cron-task

Celery and django does not work as expected.

I'm trying to create a little task to get to know Celery better.

Implemented a simple print to analyze the output and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong.

Follow the code below.

I thank you for your attention.

**init**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Task

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import task
@task()
def task_number_one():
    print('okokokokokokokokok')
```

Celery

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sistema.settings')
app = Celery('sistema')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Setting

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://REDIS:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://REDIS:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/Recife'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-number-one': {
        'task': 'base.tasks.task_number_one',
        'schedule': 30.0
    }
}
```

Comand

```
celery -A sistema worker -l info && celery -A sistema beat -l info
```

Comment: Would you post the last cmd output? when you run the last command it shows the list of task. `task_number_one` should be present in it. If not celery is not able to find the task.

Comment: You should run command `celery -A sistema beat -l info` in a separated terminal. Also documentation says that you should use `@shared_task` instead of `@task` decorator.

Comment: Netro - [tasks]
  . base.tasks.task_number_one
  . sistema.celery.debug_task

Comment: pako - I'm running separately and with share_task continue with no output. Nothing happens.

Comment: i would suggest running the task without the beat. If it works then use celery beat.

Comment: Netro - It Works.